# c#. How to get the product of two listboxes?

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I want to get the product of these listboxes. `listboxQuantity` and the `listboxPrice`.

[image: sample]

How can I get the product of `listboxQuantity` and `listboxPrice` and show on the `listboxTotal`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do with one simple for loop

assuming the two list boxes have the same length

```
  for (int i = 0; i < listboxQuantity.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var A = Convert.ToInt32(listboxQuantity.Items[i]);
            var B = Convert.ToInt32(listboxPrice.Items[i]);
            listboxTotal.Items.Add(A * B);
```

a sample output for two lists

[image]

Comment: thanks but i'm getting this error.An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the answer now. The items in my listboxes came from my database that is why your codes didn't work so i tries a Mysql command and it worked. Thanks